# Binary Tree: Finding the same values

Tags: c, data-structures, insert, find, binary-search-tree

I've been slowly writing a program and trying to teach myself binary trees. This program is a phone book that uses the tree to store its data. I am currently stuck on my findOrInsert function. Originally i had it just insert the data into an open area. Now i want to check if that data already exist before adding it. If it does then just return out of the function prompting the user there was already the same data. I've tried a few things but no luck. I may just try to rewrite it from scratch. Before that i wanted to see if i could get any help.

This is what i currently have.

```
struct treeNode * findOrInsert(struct treeNode *p, Entry e) {

    if (p == NULL) {
        p = createNode(NULL, NULL, e);
    }
    else if (strcmp(e.fName, p->data.fName) < 0) {
        p->left = findOrInsert(p->left, e);
    }
    else if (strcmp(e.fName, p->data.fName) > 0) {
        p->right = findOrInsert(p->right, e);
    }
    else {
        if (strcmp(e.lName, p->data.lName) < 0) {
            p->left = findOrInsert(p->left, e);
        }
        else if (strcmp(e.lName, p->data.lName) > 0) {
            p->right = findOrInsert(p->right, e);
        }
        else {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

struct treeNode * createNode(struct treeNode *q, struct treeNode *r, Entry e) {
     struct treeNode * newNode;
     newNode = (struct treeNode*)(malloc(sizeof(struct treeNode)));
     newNode->data = e;
     newNode->left = q;
     newNode->right = r;
     return newNode;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just simply add another check after

```
if (p == NULL) {
    p = createNode(NULL, NULL, e);
}
```

to see whether the first and last names of `p` and `e` are equal? (assuming of course that each entry in your tree has a first and last name). I say after this statement because you don't wanna compare a null object to `e`. So once you confirm that `p` does exist, you should check if the first and last names of `e` are equal to those of `p`. If so, then print out that `e` already exists in the tree or whatever and return `p` to end the recursion (an alternative to returning something is to throw an exception but that would stop the execution of the program). It should look something like this,

```
else if (strcmp(e.fName, p->data.fName) == 0 && strcmp(e.lName, p->data.lName) == 0) {
    printf("Entry already exists in tree");
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Honestly thought i tried that. Must've done something different. It seems to work now. Thank you!